# Internet recovery mode not working

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, internet, recovery

I have got macbook pro early 2011 model. Initially it came with Mac OS X Lion. Later on I upgraded it to Mavericks.
Recently I thought of upgrading it to Yosemite which I did. On successful installation I realised that It is extremely slow and 
found out that it is encrypting my whole hard disk. I left it for hours and hours but it looked like it stuck on that process.
And also did not allow me to stop the process. I turned off my macbook using power button kind of hard stop thing. When I tried to 
turn it on, it stuck on safe mode and nothing was happening. I could not log back in and I tried all the diifferent methods like PRAM reset, 
safe mode, disk utility tool to repair the disk but nothing seemed to work. Luckily I had backup in Time machine from last 
year which restored my system back to Mavericks. I started using it and it was working fine. Yesterday while closing my
system I used Power button and did that forced shut down kind of thing again and since then it is not turning back on properly.
it keeps going to safe mode. From safe mode I tried to restart the system but since then it stuck on Grey Barred Circle thing.

I decided  to use Internet recovery method when all other methods failed including safe mode, pram reset, single user command.
It looked like I will be able to restore my mac using my back up on time machine in external hard disk but it stuck on 85% 
twice. And now when I am trying to re-install the orignal version of Lion OS X which came with my macbook using internet recovery mode
it is giving me an error, "you cant upgrade this version because newer version is installed". Please help me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

To use internet recovery you will have to format your boot drive using disk utility ⌘r. After you have formatted the drive you will be able to boot into internet recovery ⌘^r. That will allow you to downgrade back to lion. I hope that this helps.

Answer (score -1):

To fix your Mac, you have to boot onto the Recovery HD, then download the software. For a the official documentation, follow the link. http://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT4718

Comment: please explain with details